# Mixture Problem help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, chemistry

I want to know if what I did is correct.

The problem is:

"A mixture A has a 2% hydrogen solution and a mixture B has a 1.5% of this same solution. How much Mix B must be added to 6 ounces of Mix A in order to get a value of 0.51?"

$$0.02(6)+0.015B=0.51$$
$$0.12+0.015B=0.51$$
$$0.015B=0.51-0.12$$
$$0.015B=0.39$$
$$\frac{0.015B}{0.015}=\frac{0.39}{0.015}$$
$$B=26$$

Therefore, 26 ounces of mixture B must be added to obtain 0.51 of hydrogen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

Alternatively, we can approach the problem like this. First factor out a $0.005$:

$$0.005(4 \cdot 6 + 3B) = 0.51$$
$$0.005\cdot 3(4 \cdot 2 + B) = 0.51$$
$$\frac{0.005\cdot3(8 + B)}{0.005\cdot3} = \frac{0.51}{0.005 \cdot 34}$$
$$8 +B = 34$$
$$B = 26$$

which is the same process, but using the integers, which makes it much easier.

Comment: Yet another method is to further factor out a $3$ after the first step, like this: $0.005\cdot 3(4 \cdot 2 + B) = 0.51$.